# Drupal Userpoints module

Tags: drupal, userpoints

Is there already an update for the userpoints_role mod?

I have a userpoints system implemented for drupal 7.x but i want it to give roles automaticly as users gain or lose karma, i do not have a clue how to do this,
so any help on this matter would be helpful ;)

I also want to have some sort of Like/disliking function, but i don't know how to do this.

thanks in advance,
jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request about giving/removing roles as users gain/lose points should already be implemented in [User Points Contributed modules](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib).

For a like/dislike feature, take a look at the [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module.

Comment: could you take a look at my other question plz?, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183324/drupal-badges-system-adding-a-badge-gives-an-error

thanks ;)